# Spring Data Jpa - Composite primary key issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, spring-data

I've used the play-spring-data-jpa template to start off a project and

I've been having issues trying to make hibernate map to a join table that uses a composite primary key.

The database that I'm connecting to is an existing mysql one.

Please see below:

SQL:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `text_advertising`.`campaign_item_slots` (
  `campaign_item_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `advert_slot_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaign_item_id`, `advert_slot_id`),
  INDEX `fk_campaign_item_slots_2_idx` (`advert_slot_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_item_id`)
    REFERENCES `text_advertising`.`campaign_items` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`advert_slot_id`)
    REFERENCES `text_advertising`.`advert_slots` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

CampaignItemSlot Class:

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_item_slots")
public class CampaignItemSlot implements Serializable{
 
 @EmbeddedId
 CampaignItemSlotId campaignItemSlotId;
 
    private boolean active;
    
    private Timestamp date_created;

    private Timestamp date_updated;

}
```

CampaignItemSlotId Class

```html
@Embeddable
public class CampaignItemSlotId implements Serializable{

  @Column(name="advert_slot_id")
  public long advertSlot;
  
  @Column(name="campaign_item_id")
  public long campaignItem;
  
}
```

When I set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate" then I get the following error:

```html
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in text_advertising.campaign_item_slots
```

When I set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update" then an id field is automatically created in the campaign_item_slots table as shown when I do a show create table. This is not what I want:

```html
| campaign_item_slots | CREATE TABLE `campaign_item_slots` (
  `campaign_item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `advert_slot_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `advertSlot_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaignItem_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaign_item_id`,`advert_slot_id`),
  KEY `fk_campaign_item_slots_2_idx` (`advert_slot_id`),
  KEY `FK_q87o53119u79073jwttacsqta` (`advertSlot_id`),
  KEY `FK_es60h5vj30rllkf0js1qy642y` (`campaignItem_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_es60h5vj30rllkf0js1qy642y` FOREIGN KEY (`campaignItem_id`) REFERENCES `campaign_items` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_1` FOREIGN KEY (`campaign_item_id`) REFERENCES `campaign_items` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_campaign_item_slots_2` FOREIGN KEY (`advert_slot_id`) REFERENCES `advert_slots` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_q87o53119u79073jwttacsqta` FOREIGN KEY (`advertSlot_id`) REFERENCES `advert_slots` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This is my build.sbt:

```html
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  javaJpa,  
  javaWs % "test",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-jpa" % "1.8.0.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "4.1.4.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "4.1.4.RELEASE" % "test", javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),  
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.8.Final",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
  "org.json" % "json" % "20090211"
 )

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

I've tried many different combinations of using IdClass and EmbeddedId etc as described on this site: [mapping variations](http://www.kawoolutions.com/Technology/JPA,_Hibernate,_and_Co./JPA_Composite_Key_Variants)

So whichever combination of things I do try, after some fiddling I get to the same error of:

```html
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: id in text_advertising.campaign_item_slots
```

I'm starting to wonder if it's a spring data issue.

Would really appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no issue with the way you have combined idClass and Embedded. I am able to get you your code working. SInce you already have the schema defined why whould you want to use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. Why not just not set the property at all ?

Comment: Thanks ArunM for running the code. The config I've provided in my post just did not want to work for me at all. Please see the answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the config below did it for me:

CampaignItemSlot.java

```html
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "campaign_item_slots")
public class CampaignItemSlot implements Serializable{
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private CampaignItemSlotPk campaignItemSlotPk;    

    @MapsId("advert_slot_id")
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="advert_slot_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    })
    @ManyToOne AdvertSlot advertSlot;
    
    @MapsId("campaign_item_id")
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="campaign_item_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    })
    @ManyToOne CampaignItem campaignItem;    
    
    private boolean active;
    
    private Timestamp date_created;

    private Timestamp date_updated;

 public CampaignItemSlot() {
  super();
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public CampaignItemSlotPk getCampaignItemSlotPk() {
  return campaignItemSlotPk;
 }

 public void setCampaignItemSlotPk(CampaignItemSlotPk campaignItemSlotPk) {
  this.campaignItemSlotPk = campaignItemSlotPk;
 }

 public boolean isActive() {
  return active;
 }

 public void setActive(boolean active) {
  this.active = active;
 }

 public Timestamp getDate_created() {
  return date_created;
 }

 public void setDate_created(Timestamp date_created) {
  this.date_created = date_created;
 }

 public Timestamp getDate_updated() {
  return date_updated;
 }

 public void setDate_updated(Timestamp date_updated) {
  this.date_updated = date_updated;
 }

 public AdvertSlot getAdvertSlot() {
  return advertSlot;
 }

 public void setAdvertSlot(AdvertSlot advertSlot) {
  this.advertSlot = advertSlot;
 }

 public CampaignItem getCampaignItem() {
  return campaignItem;
 }

 public void setCampaignItem(CampaignItem campaignItem) {
  this.campaignItem = campaignItem;
 }
 
}
```

CampaignItemSlotPK.java

```html
package models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Embeddable
public class CampaignItemSlotPk implements Serializable{
    
    @Column(name="campaign_item_id")
    private long campaignItem;

    @Column(name="advert_slot_id")
    private long advertSlot;

 public CampaignItemSlotPk() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }

 public long getCampaignItem() {
  return campaignItem;
 }

 public void setCampaignItem(long campaignItem) {
  this.campaignItem = campaignItem;
 }

 public long getAdvertSlot() {
  return advertSlot;
 }

 public void setAdvertSlot(long advertSlot) {
  this.advertSlot = advertSlot;
 }


}
```

build.sbt

```html
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.0.Final",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
```

This fixed it.